# Augmented reality, drawing a polygon using ArView and pARK sample iOS SDK

Tags: ios5, sdk, camera, polygon, gyroscope

I'm trying to implement an idea and I'm having a look at ArView of the Apple's pARK sample ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/pARk/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011083 ).

Instead of a single Point (coordinate referenced), i would like to draw a polygon to the ground. When the user points the device camera to the area where the polygon's coordinates have been set, the polygon will appear on the device screen.

As totally new with Augmented reality concept and with objective c, can someone guide me and point to the right path.

Thanks,
Zenon.